# How do I convert or create .NET v3.5 solution in C++ VS2012 (specifically the toolset)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have a library that I need to use in VS2012 C++ solution that requires .NET 3.5. I understand that I can change the framework setting in project file but v90 tool set is not listed even though I have previous VS versions installed. Is there a manual process I can follow to allow this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Be aware: v90 is VS2008!!! You need v100 (V2010) or v110 (VS2012)!

If you want to change the .NET version, the you need to take a look at the following:

There is no option in the project settings to change this. You must manually edit the project file.

It is still not possible to change the target framework in the VS2010 or VS2012 IDE in the project settings.
The only way to change it, is to manually edit the vcxproj file. For this you need to do the following:

1. Right-click on the projectin Solution Explorer and select "Unload project"

   The again do a right-click on the unloaded project in the Solution Explorer and select "Edit .vcxproj"

   In the porject XML file search for the node "<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">"

   In this node, find the sub node "<TargetFrameworkVersion>" (if it does not exists, you must add one)

   The inner text of this node defines the target framework version. It can be one of the following values: **v2.0,v3.0, v3.5 v4.0 or v4.5 (only VS2012)**

   Save the vcxproj Datei and close it

   The again do a right-click on the unloaded project in the Solution Explorer and select "Reload Project"

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <ProjectGuid>{089A9EBF-5149-462A-BC7E-2B1B59DE123C}</ProjectGuid>
  <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
  <RootNamespace>CPP_VS2010</RootNamespace>
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See also: http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2014/02/06/change-target-framework-in-ccli-for-vs20102012/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been able to change the version in the project file to v3.5 but don't I need to also change the toolset to match that .net version (well thats the way I understood it I am probably wrong). The reason is I am still having issues with integrating package error as follows

Comment: ok all fixed now, it was actually showing metadata errors due to /clr:pure change to /clr now it is all working.